# print output in 1 line separated by commas

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 1 list:

```
mylist=[John, Stefan, Bjarke, Eric, Weirdo]
```

I want to print the whole thing in one line separated by commas using a for loop, like:

```
for x in mylist:
    print x
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
print ','.join(mylist)
```

or if John Stefan etc are not already strings:

```
print ','.join(str(o) for o in mylist)
```

Comment: Even better is to use a generator in the second example instead of a list by just dropping the square brackets.

Comment: Sorry, was not familiar with stackoverflow enough, it isn't displaying my edit comments. Improved per Michael suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are smarter, and more 'Pythonic'. But if you really need a loop:

```
for item in mylist:
    print item + ',',  # <<<---- here, have a look to the trailing coma!
```

But this will let one space at next printing *before* the print. If you use `sys.stdout`, the printing will start directly after previous printing:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def t():
...     for i in (1, 4, 2):
...         print i + ',',
...     sys.stdout.write('<>')
...     for i in (3, 5):
...         print i + ',',
>>> t()
1, 4, 2,<> 3, 5,
```

`sys.stdout.write` is not adding spaces, and `'\r` will make printing to start back at beginning of line. This may be useful for refreshed display in command line.

So, to answer to your question:

```
for item in mylist:
    sys.stdout.write(item + ',')
```

But this line will end with a coma, which is not the case with `str.join` function.

Comment: Yes, this is a good option for quick display. And as it adds space automatically, it provides readable output with very simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
print ','.join(mylist)
```

A for loop is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, there's the Perl-esque hax0ring way:

```
print repr(mylist)[1:-1]
```

;)